# Removing html file extensions from website urls

Tags: html, .htaccess

Im editing my .htaccess file in the root folder of my website server to get rid of all the .html extensions in the URL's (4 in total) and I save it and its not working. Obviously something I'm doing wrong...

This is what i have in .htaccess:

```
# Begin Muse Generated redirects
# End Muse Generated redirects
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you must use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have done a file search on my server for .htaccess and added this to all files that are presented and the extension still remain in the url???

Comment: Can you share your website and the .htaccess lines you currently have done so I can take a look. Omit anything you feel violates security.

Comment: Its ok I have got past this issue, however have encountered another hickup. I have just posted another question